# Pattern.compile() using a string

Tags: java, regex

Consider this code:

```
String path = "c:\\temp";
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(".*filename.XLS.*.\\d{8}_\\d{6}");
```

How can I replace the first ".*" in myPattern so that path is included in the Regex ?
Something along the lines of

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(path + "filename.XLS.*.\\d{8}_\\d{6}");
```

which obviously does not work .. :)

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: No need to be unpleasant - I was not familiar with the concept of accepted answers. Andreas_D answered and I accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the backslashes twice:

```
String path = "c:\\\\temp";
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(path + "filename.XLS.*.\\d{8}_\\d{6}");
```

Once for java and than again for the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks ! In retrospect this makes sense.. :)